# Question on Cadences

Tags: theory

I am working on hearing cadences in music. So far, the only possibilities are full or half cadences. I have to write out a pulse graph and indicate above the graph with arrows to show where each of these cadences (2) arrives on the final chord.

Here is one of the examples I am having trouble with: https://streamable.com/o9lpcs

Comment: How are you supposed to mark up a graph through the web site? When is the score?

Comment: @Michael Curtis I do not have a score only the audio file

Comment: It just looks like an audio player in a web page. Literally _how_ will you mark pulses?

Comment: on a piece of paper

Comment: That means you need to transcribe the music first. Otherwise how can anyone know where your markings go in the actual music. It seems like a poorly designed quiz. It ought to provide a score not an audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Full cadences (Perfect in UK) go from V to I. Half cadences (imperfect in UK) go the opposite way - I to V. So if the music sounds as though it's at a finish point, it's V>I, if it sounds like it's just having a little break, and there needs to be more to end, it's I>V. Cadences only involve the final two harmonies.

Half cadencies often go I>V, but could also be ii>V, V/V>V, vi>V or IV>V, so the final chord is the telling one here.

Comment: how would I write that out as a pulse graph to indicate the cadences above the graph?

Comment: @DylanCataldo This is something you're doing on your own, yes? (As opposed to a class, where the teacher should answer about how to do the pulse graph.) If on your own, maybe just make an especially large arrow pointing to the pulse on which the cadence ends.

Comment: In my experience, V-I are called "authentic" cadences, and of those, "perfect" are those in root position with the leading tone-tonic in the top voice," while "imperfect" are those which don't meet that definition of perfect.  "Half" cadences are any which end on V, and aren't called referred to as perfect or imperfect.  However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence#Half_cadence) recognizes the alternative (or primary?) terminology as you've used it.  Just thought I'd mention the idea of "Authentic" cadences as that's how I've always referred to them.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - On the right of the Atlantic, we tend to call all V>I perfect. True, there are degrees of authentic. Plagal and interrrupted (again, re-named in US) are still to be encountered, it seems.

Comment: I also use plagal for IV-I.  I'm assuming "interrupted" is what I'd call "deceptive," which is a V-VI cadence?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - yes, except deceptive (interrupted) is more often V>vi.

Comment: Depending on the key, yes that's true.  Most of my compositions are in minor keys, and I love playing around the dominant with different flavors of aug 6th chords, so in my world, they're almost always major! :D

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - never considered what an interrupted cadence would be in a minor key. Going to do some homework!

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 This is how I learned them in theory class in the US as well.